# Cartodb Torque map

Tags: carto, cartocss, torque

I cannot figure out how to use the torque map:

A typical row of my data, which is named torquedata3, looks like :
 `[nodenumber, lat,long,time,value]`.

I have multiple rows at the same time with each row having a different "value" ranging from 0-7. I simply want to display at each different node a different color depending on the value.

Sorry for how easy my question may seem but I can not get it to work, I have tried all sorts of different `torque-aggregation-functions(avg, round(avg()), min, max, count)`.

Below is the code I am using (field 4 has the time and field_5 has my values I want to display).

```
/** torque visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:30;

-torque-animation-duration:60;

-torque-time-attribute:"field_4";

-torque-aggregation-function:"count(field_5)";

-torque-resolution:1;

-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}


torquedata3{
  marker-width: 4;

  [value = 0] { marker-fill: #229A00; }

  [value = 1] { marker-fill: #0F3B82; }

  [value = 2] { marker-fill: #7B00B4; }

  [value = 3] { marker-fill: #000000; }

  [value = 4] { marker-fill: #FF2900; }

  [value = 5] { marker-fill: #CC4C02; }

  [value = 6] { marker-fill: #993404; }

  [value = 7] { marker-fill: #662506; }

}
```

---

I am now trying to create a heatmap.

I have changed some of the commands to

```
Map {
-torque-frame-count:30;
-torque-animation-duration:90;
-torque-time-attribute:"field_4";
-torque-aggregation-function:"sum(field_5)";
-torque-resolution:1;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#torquedata3{
  image-filters: colorize-alpha(red); 
  marker-file: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.cartodb.assets.static/alphamarker.png);
 marker-fill-opacity:0.5*[value];
 marker-width: 5;
```

But I cannot do this multiplication on the value, I get the error message:
Invalid value for marker-fill-opacity, the type float is expected. 0.5*[value](of type field) was given. I would like to use the marker file that fades in order to get a heat map type visual as opposed to the dots that do not fade into each other as much.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to GIS stack exchange. I formatted your code using the CODE tag for easier readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your dataset according to your description (I highly recommend next time give us the link anyway). [Here](https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/tables/new_table) is my dataset, called `new_table`. It contains the following columns: `cartodb_id`(numeric), `the_geom`(geometry/points), `city`(string) and `country`(string), `order_num`(numeric, this should be your `field_4`) and `colors`(numeric, and this should be as field_5).

If you select Torque Map in CARTO Wizard and change the CartoCSS a little bit in order to add the colors, you end up with a block of CartoCSS code like this:

```
/** torque visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:256;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"order_num";
-torque-aggregation-function:"sum(colors)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#new_table{
  comp-op: lighter;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 0;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  marker-fill: #0F3B82;
}
#new_table[frame-offset=1] {
 marker-width:8;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.45; 
}
#new_table[frame-offset=2] {
 marker-width:10;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.225; 
}

#new_table{
  [value = 1] { marker-fill: #FFCC00; }

  [value = 2] { marker-fill: #FFA300; }

  [value = 3] { marker-fill: #FF5C00; }

  [value = 4] { marker-fill: #FF6600; }

  [value = 5] { marker-fill: #FF2900; }

  [value = 6] { marker-fill: #F11810; }

  [value = 7] { marker-fill: #B40903; }

}
```

I have reused the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ramiroaznar/06aeec0cf383318c1a9821305e83acb7) (where I also add a bubble effect), and [this is the resulting map](https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/viz/3d138870-4994-11e6-acc4-0ecd1babdde5/public_map).

Take good care to set `torque-time-attribute` parameter to your date or numeric field that you want your data-points to be ordered. In addition, you should set `torque-aggregation-function` attribute to other aggregation operation but `count`. What [Torque.js](https://carto.com/torque/) is doing is aggregating in a third dimension (usually time) and apply that formula. So if you use count with just 7 rows with different values, you will end up with `value` equal to `1` each time/bin.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work. I also read somewhere that [value = 0] does not work, is this true? Some of the elements in my field_5 are valued 0.

Comment: The value `0 ` does not work with `count` aggregation function, because you always get more than one figure. Last, if your question has been answered, please set as answered.